# Не отправляться boundary в заголовках запроса

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, multipart

Для загрузки файлов на сервер, выполняю POST с помощью multipart/form-data, для этого использую либу backbone-model-file-upload. В теле запроса boundary отправляется, а вот в заголовках boundary нету (при этом `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`). Подскажите в чем причина отсутствия параметра `boundary`? Ниже мой код:

```
var fileObject = $('input')[0].files[0];
var FileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'upload',
    fileAttribute: 'attachment'
});
var fileModel = new FileModel();

fileModel.save(
    {
        'attachment': fileObject,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'name': 'valueName'
    },
    {headers: {
            'Accept': 'myAccept',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если самостоятельно устанавливать заголовок `Content-Type`, то `boundary` не будет вставлен в залоговки запроса.